# How to resolve IndexError: index 754 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 754 on applying TransactionEncoder() on a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataset of shape 754 rows and 6366 columns. I applied TransactionEncoder() on it, before applyting Apriori algorithm.

My code:

```
import mlxtend
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(df1)
te_ary2=te_ary.transform(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(te_ary2, columns=te.columns_)
```

The error is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-563ab8f9870d> in <module>
----> 1 te_ary2=te_ary.transform(df1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\preprocessing\transactionencoder.py in transform(self, X, sparse)
    127                 for item in transaction:
    128                     col_idx = self.columns_mapping_[item]
--> 129                     array[row_idx, col_idx] = True
    130         return array
    131 

IndexError: index 754 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 754
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: legal index would be 0 to 753, right?  Why is row_idx 754?

Comment: I did df1.tail() and found last index to be 753. Still it is showing like this.......

Comment: Please post a [mre]